# how to enable 2 module in joomla php

Tags: php, joomla, module, for-loop

I have created 2 module for joomla. When I enable any one its working fine with joomla in left and right. But when I enable both the website is not working...its not display any website content.

Please help me how I can enable more then 2 module.

Thanks,
Manoj Singhal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can enabled two module at a time with giving different position to them.
whichever module you are going to enabled and then site contents not showing means that module not compatible with joomla verion.
tell me your module names so I can help u more.